# ASP.NET private member field loses value on postback

Tags: asp.net, postback

Consider the following code:

```
    public partial class TeacherControlPanel : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected string username = string.Empty;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            username = (string)Request.QueryString["username"];

            Ice_Web_Portal.BO.Teacher teacher = Ice_Web_Portal.BO.Teacher.GetTeacherByUsername(username);

            if (teacher != null)
            {
                labUsername.Text = username;
                labName.Text = teacher.TeacherName;
                labTeacherCode.Text = teacher.TeacherCode;

                Dept dept = teacher.Department;

                if (dept != null)
                {
                    labDepartment.Text = dept.DeptName;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //labErrorMessage.Text = "No teacher found";
            }
        }

        protected void btnSendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect(@"~/Teacher/TeacherComposeMail.aspx?username=mahabub" + username);            
        }
}
```

In this code, when I am declaring 'username' as private, it is initialized to null after subsequent post backs.

Why?

What is the secret?

Comment: Are you saying that the code works as written, but when you change username to a private variable it fails?

Comment: Is it initialized to null or string.Empty?

Comment: @Fredou, Getting a Teacher's data by his unique username. No partial class.

Comment: JMSA - the problem is probably in the code the does the postback, this seems ok. Please post that code.

Comment: @Chris Pebble, Yes you got it.

Comment: Can you show us the code that doesn't work?  Simply switching to private should have no bearing.  There shouldn't be any serialization type things going on in the background (which might have explained things).

Comment: @John Fisher, just make it 'private string username = string.Empty;'

Comment: @John Fisher, none of my classes are Serializable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because ASP.NET is stateless meaning it does not keep it state from post back to postback.  Save the user to the viewstate, session, or application to see it on postback to postback.

```
#region UserName
public string UserName
{
    get
    {
        if (this.ViewState["UserName"] == null)
            return string.Empty;

        return (string)this.ViewState["UserName"];
    }
    set { this.ViewState["UserName"] = value; }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: but he's doing `username = (string)Request.QueryString["username"];` on every page load.

Comment: @David Basarab, I am not requesting a solution. I am trying to know the difference of effect btwn. protected vs private in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Every time you do any postback, even for "simple" things like button click events, you're working with a *new instance* of the page class.  That's ASP.Net 101.

Comment: If you redirect to a new page or load a page with a new query string, that is not a postback. If you process a button click event on a page with a query string, that is a postback and the query string is sent with the postback http request. Either way, it's still a new instance of the page class.

Comment: I did not find my answer relating protected vs private.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the username field as private or protected has no bearing on this situation.  The only bearing protected/private would have is the accessibility of the variable outside the class or in inherited members.

I believe this is likely a lifecycle problem.

When you navigate to this page for the first time, user name will only have a value if the query string was set for the request.  So, "/TeacherControlPanel.aspx" will have a user name with no value, but "/TeacherControlPanel.aspx?username=SomeUserName".  In these cases, the field username is only going to have a value if one is set.  And if no querystring is set, then when the page processes the button click event, the load will fire, no query string set means that username will be null, which means that the click event will have nothing to append to the redirect string.

So the question is, in your application, what navigation path are you using to get to TeacherControlPanel.aspx?

Comment: in addition, a protected field will be visible on the page (TeacherControlPanel.aspx, on <% %> statements), while a private field isn't.